# Django ORM - Join many-to-many with through table

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 models:

- **Task**: A task, can be assigned to many employees.
- **AssignedUser**: (Bridge table) Store employees assigned to tasks

  - `completed`: Indicate whether the `employee` has done the assigned task yet.
- **Employee**: An employee, can work on many tasks. ([Extends from Django's user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model))

```py
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    detail = models.TextField()
    employees = models.ManyToManyField('Employee', through='AssignedUser', related_name='tasks')

class AssignedUser(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.ForeignKey(to=Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    # Note - department field is not relevant to this question.
```

If I want to select a task name and the assigned employee's username who hasn't done the task yet (`completed=False`) how can I do that with Django's ORM?

Here's the equivalent SQL I wrote for the desired result which I have no idea how to achieve that with Django's ORM.

```sql
SELECT t.name, u.username
FROM appname_task t
JOIN appname_assigneduser au
    ON (t.id = au.work_id AND au.completed = false)
JOIN appname_employee ae
    ON (au.employee_id = ae.id)
JOIN auth_user u
    ON (ae.user_id = u.id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain this with:

```
from django.db.models import F

Task.objects.filter(assigneduser__completed=False).values(
    'name', username=F('employees__user__username')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. May I ask you...can you explain the `F('employees__user__username')` part?

Comment: `F` refers to a field (column). SO we here refer to the `username` of the `user` of the `employees` that are joined.